# Failed calling webhook "mutate.runner.actions.summerwind.dev": x509: certificate signed by unknown authority

Tags: kubernetes, github-actions, github-actions-runners

```
Kubernetes: v1.19.9-gke.1900 
Helm actions-runner-controller: 0.12.7
```

I have CRDs created by [Github Actions Controller](https://actions-runner-controller.github.io/actions-runner-controller):

```
❯ kubectl api-resources | grep summerwind.dev
horizontalrunnerautoscalers                    actions.summerwind.dev/v1alpha1   true         HorizontalRunnerAutoscaler
runnerdeployments                              actions.summerwind.dev/v1alpha1   true         RunnerDeployment
runnerreplicasets                              actions.summerwind.dev/v1alpha1   true         RunnerReplicaSet
runners                                        actions.summerwind.dev/v1alpha1   true         Runner
runnersets                                     actions.summerwind.dev/v1alpha1   true         RunnerSet
```

And also I have a sample file with two simplified resources: pod and runner

```
❯ cat test.yml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: pod-1
spec:
  containers:
  - name: main
    image: busybox

---
apiVersion: actions.summerwind.dev/v1alpha1
kind: Runner
metadata:
  name: runner-1
spec:
  organization: my-org
  env: []
```

Now, when I run apply to both these resources, the **Pod** works good but the **Runner** fails:

```
❯ kubectl apply -f test.yml
pod/pod-1 created
Error from server (InternalError): error when creating "test.yml": Internal error occurred: failed calling webhook "mutate.runner.actions.summerwind.dev": Post "https://actions-runner-controller-webhook.tools.svc:443/mutate-actions-summerwind-dev-v1alpha1-runner?timeout=30s": x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

As you see, this call goes to the MutatingWebhookConfiguration. And this webhook sends request to the Controller that prints only:

```
❯ kubectl -n tools logs actions-runner-controller-6cd6fbdd56-qlzrd -c manager
...
http: TLS handshake error from 10.128.0.3:59736: remote error: tls: bad certificate
```

**QUESTION**:
What is the next step for troubleshooting?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you try to check and delete validatingwebhookconfiguration and mutatingwebhookconfiguration first:

1. Check

```
kubectl get validatingwebhookconfiguration -A
kubectl get mutatingwebhookconfiguration -A
```

2. Delete

```
kubectl delete mutatingwebhookconfiguration actions-runner-controller-mutating-webhook-configuration
kubectl delete validatingwebhookconfiguration actions-runner-controller-validating-webhook-configuration
```

Comment: thanks :-) but the question is 2 years old.